# Split Data and transforming them into Columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2014

I have an Input table as under

```
Id  Data
1   Column1: Value1
2   Column2: Value11
3   Column3: Value111
4   Column1: Value2
5   Column2: Value22
6   Column3: Value222
```

I am looking for an output as under

```
Column1      Column2    Column3
Value1       Value11    Value111
Value2       Value22    Value222
```

How can I achieve so? It could have been done easily by using a WHILE LOOP and by a bit of mathematical logic, but I am looking for a more optimized one if possible by only SELECT queries (no LOOPS).

I have tried also by splitting using (':') as delimiter and then transforming ROWS to COLUMNS (PIVOT) but somewhat could not be able to proceed. (That's my thought, peoples may have more better thoughts).

My shot so far

```
Declare @t table(Id int identity(1,1),Data varchar(1000))
Insert into @t Values
    ('Column1: Value1'),('Column2: Value11'),('Column3: Value111')
    ,('Column1: Value2'),('Column2: Value22'),('Column3: Value222')

Select *
FROM @t
SELECT 
 F1.id,
 F1.Data,
 O.splitdata 
FROM
 (
 SELECT *,
 cast('<X>'+replace(F.Data,':','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as xmlfilter from @t F
 )F1
 CROSS APPLY
 ( 
 SELECT fdata.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as splitdata 
 FROM f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') as fdata(D)) O
```

Comment: do you have a fixed number of columns and are they ordered the way it seems to be on your sample?

Comment: is `Column1      Column2    Column3` is column name or just a values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Declare @t table(Id int identity(1,1),Data varchar(1000))
Insert into @t Values
    ('Column1: Value1'),('Column2: Value11'),('Column3: Value111')
    ,('Column1: Value2'),('Column2: Value22'),('Column3: Value222');

WITH Splitted AS
(
     SELECT *
           ,CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(F.Data,':','</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS xmlfilter 
     FROM @t AS F
)
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY xmlfilter.value('X[1]','varchar(max)') ORDER BY Id) AS Inx 
          ,xmlfilter.value('X[1]','varchar(max)') AS ColName
          ,xmlfilter.value('X[2]','varchar(max)') AS ColVal
    FROM Splitted
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    MAX(ColVal) FOR ColName IN(Column1,Column2,Column3)
) AS p
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work if you want a pure SQL solution:

```
Select [Column1], [Column2], [Column3] From (
    Select col, val, id = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by d.col order by d.id)
    From (
         Select id
            , col = LEFT(Data, CHARINDEX(':', Data)-1)
            , val = RIGHT(Data, LEN(DATA) - CHARINDEX(':', Data))

         From @t
    ) as d
) as p
pivot(
    MAX(val)
    FOR col in([Column1], [Column2], [Column3])
) as piv
```

But it supposes that data for Row 1 are always before data for Row 2. There is no way to distinguish them using your sample.

If the number of column is not fixed, it has to use Dynamic SQL.

SQL Server may not be the best options for this kind of thing.

With Dynamic SQL, the above query would be like this one:

```
create table #t(Id int identity(1,1),Data varchar(1000))
Insert into #t Values
    ('Column1: Value1'),('Column2: Value11'),('Column3: Value111')
    ,('Column1: Value2'),('Column2: Value22'),('Column3: Value222')

Declare @sql nvarchar(max)

Select @sql = '
        Select '+left(c, len(c)-1)+' From (
        Select col, val, id = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by d.col order by d.id)
        From (
             Select id
                , col = LEFT(Data, CHARINDEX('':'', Data)-1)
                , val = RIGHT(Data, LEN(DATA) - CHARINDEX('':'', Data))

             From #t
        ) as d
    ) as p
    pivot(
        MAX(val)
        FOR col in('+left(c, len(c)-1)+')
    ) as piv
'
From (
    Select Distinct '['+LEFT(Data, CHARINDEX(':', Data)-1)+'], '
    From #t
    FOR XML PATH('')
) as d(c)

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7e292/1/0)